# ResizeObserver not working properly for setting css-grid item width

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid, resize-observer

I have a CSS-Grid wrapper with items in. Each item has a `ResizeObserver`, listening for size changes in order to resize a chart that is rendered inside the item.

On resize, the chart `width` will be set to the items width. The problem is, that the `ResizeObserver` won't fire any events when the item is resized to a smaller width.

Here is a simple reproduction:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item" id="item-1">
    <div id="item-1-child">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  background: orange;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```js
const el = document.getElementById('item-1');
const elChild = document.getElementById('item-1-child')

const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  console.log('resize', el.offsetWidth)
  elChild.style.width = `${el.offsetWidth}px`;
});

observer.observe(el);
```

When I change the `display: grid;` on the `.wrapper` to `display: block;`, it works as intended. So something related to CSS-Grid is causing some trouble here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) property to the grid container ("wrapper"), which defines the track sizing for the grid columns. This will allow you to limit the width of the "item-1-child".

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
}

.item {
  background: orange;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}
```

The reason for this problem is that `grid-template-columns` is defaulted to `none`:

> Indicates that there is no explicit grid. Any columns will be implicitly generated and their size will be determined by the `grid-auto-columns` property.
>
> -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns#values

Then `grid-auto-columns` is defaulted to `auto`:

> Is a keyword that is identical to maximal content if it's a maximum. As a minimum it represents the largest minimum size (as specified by `min-width`/`min-height`) of the grid items occupying the grid track.
>
> -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-columns#values